# Unable to connect to mySQL from Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am able to connect via the mySQL shell, but when I try from VS Code Nodemon crashes and i get the error.
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
errno: 1045,
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
sqlState: '28000',
fatal: true

My environment variable path is set up.
I have run... ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456'
I have set up a new user, granted them full permissions and tried to connect to that user but still denied access.

````
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456'
  });
  
db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected');
    }
})

app.listen('8000', () => console.log("Server running on port 8000"));```

package.json
{
  "name": "mern-prac-2-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}

Thanks!


(edited)
Based on Juans Answer I have changed to this...

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const sequelize = new Sequelize('fake_company', 'root', '123456', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',

  });

const tryConnection = async () => { 
    try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  }
}

tryConnection();

app.listen('8000', () => console.log("Server running on port 8000"));

And am having the error ...

code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
    sql: undefined
````

Comment: Did you run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or restart your server after you changed your password?

Comment: It's not necessary to flush privileges or restart after simply changing a password. The most likely issue is that you got the password wrong.

Comment: The password is definitely not wrong, I am able to log into the shell using it. No i didn't FLUSH PRIVILEGES ill try that now.

Comment: Have done FLUSH PRIVILEGES and still same issue

Comment: Have followed answer Juan kindly provided using the sequelize package and am still getting a similar error but with "sql: undefined". Do I need to reinstall mySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I connect NodeJS con MySQL/MariaDB using sequelize package, this code is with typescript, you must change imports to require.

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

// -----------------------------------------------------
const sequelize = new Sequelize('node', 'username', 'your-password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    // logging: false
    /* one of 'mysql' | 'postgres' | 'sqlite' | 'mariadb' | 'mssql' | 'db2' | 'snowflake' | 'oracle' */
  });
  // -----------------------------------------------------

  export default sequelize;
```

//------------------------------------------------------

// Then in the server I have this code.

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import cors from "cors";

import userRoutes from '../routes/usuario.mjs';
import sequelize from '../db/connection.mjs';

class Server {
    private app: Application;
    private port: string;
    private apiPath ={
        usuarios: '/api/usuarios'
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    constructor(){
        this.app = express();
        this.port = process.env.PORT || '8000';

        // connect to DB
        this.dbConnection();
       // ...

    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect with DB
    async dbConnection(){
        try {
            await sequelize.authenticate();
            console.log('Database is connected.');
        } catch (error: any) {
            throw new Error( error.message );
        }
    }
}
```

It works porperly for my.

Comment: I installed "sequelize": "^6.28.0" and "mysql2": "^3.0.1"

Comment: I get... code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
    sql: undefined

Comment: Just using a different library won't solve the problem of a wrong password ...

Comment: the password is 100% correct, I use it to log into the shell, there must be some other reason. When I am in the shell it looks like I am using port 33060 instead of 3306. If I add port: '33060' to sequelize object it i get ... RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 5. Received 9

Comment: @Danny_P Well if you connect on a *different port* you are connecting to a *different instance* of the mysqlserver, so no wonder your password you changed on instance 1 does not work for instance 2 ...

Comment: Note that the first param in  `Sequelize('fake_company', 'username', 'your-password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  });`  must be a valid database name. So fake_company must be a database name, not a table name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sequelize, I think you can create the perfect configuration with sequelize init commands. Sequelize gives you a config file in a configuration folder like below. You have to define a database for sequelize don't forget that.

Firstly you have to install npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli for your cli commands.Then you can use sequelize init command.

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "123456",
    "database": "your db",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "query": {
      "raw": true
    },
    "options": {
      "pool": {
        "max": 5,
        "min": 0,
        "acquire": 30000,
        "idle": 10000
      }
    }
  },
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "123124",
    "database": "yourDB",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "query": {
      "raw": true
    },
    "options": {
      "pool": {
        "max": 5,
        "min": 0,
        "acquire": 30000,
        "idle": 10000
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a new user and giving it privilege will help. The root user might need root access or administrative access. And node doesn't have a root access.